# PayPal Pro : is it necessary to gather details oneself or can PayPal do that for me?

Tags: php, paypal

I know that with PayPal Pro, the user enters his information on my site and PayPal processes that in the background.

Still, is it possible to have it like with PayPal standard : the user gets redirected to PayPal site, enters his information there, pays there, and come back ?

I'm asking cause my client has PayPal Pro, however I don't feel comfortable with gathering payment data myself. I would prefer PayPal to do that for me.

Comment: Please constult PayPal documentation, I would first of all assume that this is still possible even if you're a Paypal Pro user, but please consult the docs first.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, you can use IPN.

Longer answer:

Either way you want to have an SSL certificate, and to handle various payment information.

If you're using IPN, the user gets redirected to the PayPal site, pays, and gets redirected back, and you receive a notification to one of your scripts. That script will have to check if the data you receive is similar to what you sent, and other checks. You may not receive the notification instantly, sometimes it takes a few days to get it (very rarely though).

With PayPal Pro, the user enters his credit card details and submits them. You will have to make some checks here, but after that you send the info to PayPal, and you receive the response (either success or response) - instantly.

These are the major differences, it's nothing mind boggling one way or the other, you just need to use the API documentation.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, it all sounds beyond my skills though. I created a Pay Now button leading to a PayPal page where the user can pay either with via a PP account or credit card. After successful CC payment the user is redirected to my site. Two questions:
(1) Since CC details were not exchanged between PayPal and my site, is SSL still necessary ? (2) When the user returns to my site I need to validate his registration in my PHP code, but how can I connect his successful payment with his registration details? Is there a way to transmit variables along the PP payment process?

Comment: 1. Yes, SSL is necessary in any scenario 2. Yes, you can send custom information in a `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<!-- insert custom info here -->" />`. You can find sample scripts in many places, so create a sandbox account and start playing around with it :)

Comment: Thanks Vlad. (1) I created a hidden input and I can track it until before the "[PP user], you just completed your payment" screen. On this screen, my POST variable is gone. Why is that? (2) Also, auto-redirection option is activated yet I don't get redirected, I have to click on "Return to [...] Store" so even if my POST variable was intact I would lose it when clicking on that link. Can I do something about it?